# Making an abstract object within a LocalScript (Roblox LUA)

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to add a money system to a game. I have added a script that gives $2500 in a NumberValue inside the LocalPlayer when a child is added to the players. But I'm unsure as to how I can create a NumberValue in the script and I cannot use instance.new because NumberValues are abstract. Any ideas?

EDIT- Here's some code I've tried that clones a pre-existing NumberValue

```
function AddPlayer()
    local Money = script.Parent.Money
    local Clone = Money:Clone()
    Clone.Parent = game.Players.LocalPlayer   
    Clone.Value = 2500
    Clone.Name = "Money"
end

game.Players.ChildAdded:connect(AddPlayer)
```

Comment: Could You please show some code You've tried? As-is it does not make much sense.

Comment: Well there is no code to show and it's pretty much as of now an empty function and a function connect

Comment: First of all, turn on FilteringEnabled and **don't** use LocalScripts for this stuff. This should be done *server-sided*

Comment: Ok then, I just assumed that since it was a player thing that local scripts should be used. I'm not very keen with localscripts either. also it works now, thank you!

Comment: While dealing with things locally like UI and mouse/key events use LocalScripts, when dealing with scary-important things like currency keep it server-sided so people can't exploit your game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean by that [NumberValues](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/NumberValue) are "abstract" (clarify?). But there should be nothing that prevents you from creating it using [Instance.new](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Instance_(Data_Structure))

```
local Money = Instance.new("NumberValue")
Money.Name = "Money"
Money.Value = 2500
```

And as [warspyking said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942269/making-an-abstract-object-within-a-localscript-roblox-lua#comment71067000_41942269), you should be doing this on the server, and [you should have FilteringEnabled](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=FilteringEnabled_with_the_Client-Server_Model).

Basically putting a normal script in "Game.ServerScriptService" with the code:

```
game:GetService("Players").PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)
    local Money = Instance.new("NumberValue")
    Money.Name = "Money"
    Money.Value = 2500
    Money.Parent = player
end)
```

To note is also that you should use [PlayerAdded](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Players/PlayerAdded) and not [ChildAdded](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Instance/ChildAdded), as `PlayerAdded` only triggers when a player is added, while `ChildAdded` also triggers if someone puts junk in [Game.Players](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Players).